# parsing a collection of string and scraping hebrew only

Tags: c#, string, winforms, validation, hebrew

this is the case

passes:

```
 "אבגדהו"
 "אב'גדהו"
 "אב-גדהו"
 "אב"גד"
 "אבגדהו"
 "אב.גד"
 "אבגדהו"
```

fails :

```
"א*בAb"
"א/ב1c"
```

trying the code below i am getting starnge behavior that as soon as the first fail test 
all the following that suppose to pass fail also

so the question is 
using c# winforms desktop app , what is the right way to validate string

will contain only א TO ת
will allow to contain chars `.-'`
if string contains anywhere within it a numeric, or any other language chars = fail

```
    public string OnlyHebPlusSomeSpclChars(string StrToVerify)
    {

        bool ISheb = StrToVerify.All(c => c >= 0x0580 && c <= 0x05ff);
        if (ISheb)
        {
            return StrToVerify;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";//Test String contain 1 or more invalid chars
        }

    }
```

**Update**

SO Sorry to forget to meniton the spaces are allowd . 
thar was not a password field but a f.name + l.name collection having spaces also

"אב גד הו"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fine. To explain why the second value fails is because it has an apostrophe character `'` . Same with the succeeding strings. They have either `'`, `-`, `.`, `''` (2 single apostrophes)

To fix this, you just have to add the allowable characters in your check.

```
bool ISheb = StrToVerify.All(c => (c >= 0x0580 && c <= 0x05ff)
            || c == '.' //add this
            || c == '-' //add this
            || c == '\'' //add this
            || c == ' '); //add this
```

Comment: i have updated my question, as it is all mixed non linear over 200 records per test some are ok and some are "invalid" strings

Comment: thing is, i thought the range i gave includes your addition of chars that aside, still the same beahavior - say the stream is - 1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1 gives you back 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
being 1=true , 0=false

Comment: you just edited the list to be in a straight line. this solution works as per your specification: *will contain only א TO ת
will allow to contain chars .-' if string contains anywhere within it a numeric, or any other language chars = fail*

Comment: add one more line (: for that space char, i wanna wash my eyes with it looks ...(: